# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found

Tags: php, macos, zip, macos-catalina

I have this error.

(I don't use Apache just run php script by CLI)

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found`

However it looks that `zip module` is installed.

```
$php -m | grep zip
zip
```

I have installed php by homebrew on Catalina.

```
php -v
PHP 7.4.10 (cli) (built: Sep  3 2020 18:21:42) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.10, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Is there anything I need to check??

Comment: Is the corresponding code under a namespace by any chance? In which case you'll need to reference it with `\ZipArchive` (and/or optionally `use` it on top of your script).

Answer (score 1):

For the [`ZipArchive` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) to be present, PHP needs to have the [zip extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) installed.

See [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php) for installation instructions (both Linux and Windows).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Zip extension. Depending where you are working on, it is fairly simple to install it.

**cPanel:**
Head on to 'PHP PEAR Packages' under the Software tab and search Zip and you'll find ZipArchive. You might also need to activate it manually. Head on to Software > Select PHP Version > Extensions, then check the box for Zip.

**For EC2 or any other linux hostings/servers:**

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-zip
```